# SQL.CommandText and Updates with ADODB

Tags: sql-server, vba

Dan, the code works!  I wanted to manually write my entries within the code 
 and have them entered in.  Thank you for your help!

```
Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Dim Name As String
Dim Name1 As String
Name = "test1"
Name1 = "test2"

Server_Name = "."
Database_Name = "MyDatabase"

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"

Dim SQL As ADODB.Command
Set SQL = New ADODB.Command

SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Test] SET [name] =(?) WHERE [id] = 1;"
SQL.CommandText = SQL.CommandText + "UPDATE [Mydatabase].[dbo].[Test] SET [name] =(?) WHERE [id] = 2;"


SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Name)
SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("name1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Name1)

SQL.ActiveConnection = Cn
SQL.Execute

Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Aren't you just repeatedly replacing the CommandText value here?  It will end up with the last value set.

Comment: Could you please show me the correct way?  I have no idea.

Comment: You can run each of the 3 queries in the same way you run one query: one at a time.

Comment: Using your example, you only need one update: `UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] IN (1,2,3)`

Comment: Sorry Tim, it does not work.  It updates ID's 1,2,3 with the same values.  I need a different value for each ID.

Comment: Create a Sub which performs a single update given an "id" and a "value" parameter: call that sub 3 times with the required id/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add 3 parameters, one for each value. Try:

```
SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Value1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Value1)
SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Value2", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Value2)
SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Value3", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Value3)
```

Also your code is not concatenating the separate UPDATE statements properly. This is the version with statement terminators too:

```
SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 1;"
SQL.CommandText = SQL.CommandText + "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 2;"
SQL.CommandText = SQL.CommandText + "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 3;"
```

**EDIT:**

This is the T-SQL script I used to create the database, table, and test data:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyDatabase;
GO
USE MyDatabase;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test(
     id int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY
    ,name varchar(100)
    );
INSERT INTO dbo.Test VALUES(1,''),(2,''),(3,'');
GO
```

Below is the revised code from your question I tested with. The only changes I made were the server name and table name in the second update statement, which I changed from `name` to `Test`. I didn't the `adParamInput` and `adVarchar` constants. Those were included by the ActiveX objects reference so the code works with or without then.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    Dim Name As String
    Dim Name1 As String
    Name = "test1"
    Name1 = "test2"

    Server_Name = "."
    Database_Name = "MyDatabase"

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"

    Dim SQL As ADODB.Command
    Set SQL = New ADODB.Command

    SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [MyDatabase].[dbo].[Test] SET [name] =(?) WHERE [id] = 1;"
    SQL.CommandText = SQL.CommandText + "UPDATE [Mydatabase].[dbo].[Test] SET [name] =(?) WHERE [id] = 2;"


    SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("name", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Name)
    SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("name1", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, Name1)

    SQL.ActiveConnection = Cn
    SQL.Execute

    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @codinglady, I added more information to my answer. If you sill have errors, let me know the error message.

Comment: Dan, I have included your suggestions at the top of the list.  It still updates an entire group, rather than individual rows.

Comment: Same thing happens with a single transactional SQL statement.

Comment: @codinglady, are you saying this code updates more than the 3 rows ( rows with ID values 1,2, and 3)? You're intent is to update only those 3 rows and with the same value, right?

Comment: Each row gets a different value.  There are three rows in total.

Comment: Your code updates the three rows with the same value.

Comment: I thought you wanted to update all 3 rows with the same value because the code in your question all have `Value` as the parameter value. All you need to do then is specify different values for each of the 3 parameters as in the first example.

Comment: They are in the same column, but I want each row to have a different value. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid use of default paramenter.

Comment: @codinglady, it seems you don't have the [ADO ParameterDirection](https://www.w3schools.com/asp/prop_para_direction.asp) and/or [DataType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/datatypeenum) enums referenced. Try adding `const adParamInput = 1` and `const adVarChar = 200` to your code.

Comment: Still getting  [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid use of default paramenter.  I have added the revised code to the top.

Comment: @codinglady, I ran the code  in your question. I had to change the table name in the second `UPDATE` statement to `[Mydatabase].[dbo].[name]` but it then worked as expected, updating both rows.

Comment: @codinglady, I forgot to mention that I added the declarations for name and name1 to your code for my test and set values. The default parameter error can be due to the values not being initialized.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this working code?

Comment: Dan, the code works.  But please see my edit at the very top of the page. Thank you.

Comment: @codinglady, I ran the latest code in your question and it updated the 2 existing rows successfully. When you say it doesn't seem to work, does that mean there is no error but the existing rows with Id 1 and 2 are not updated?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested)

```
Sub DoUpdate(id, newValue)

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & _
             ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"

    Dim SQL As ADODB.Command
    Set SQL = New ADODB.Command

    SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET" _
                      " [Value] = ? WHERE [id] = ?"


    SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Value", adVarChar, _
                                          adParamInput, 50, newValue)
    SQL.Parameters.Append SQL.CreateParameter("Id", adVarNumeric, _
                                          adParamInput, 50, id)

    SQL.ActiveConnection = Cn
    SQL.Execute

    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Then call like:

```
DoUpdate 1, 20
DoUpdate 2, 30
DoUpdate 3, 88
```

Comment: Sorry, Tim. It is not working.  The values are added each time a user clicks a button.  Also, I do not understand why you are changing the adVarChar to an adParamInput

Comment: There are two parameters - one for the id and one for the value: your existing one was adVarChar and I added a adVarNumeric one for the id.

Answer (score 0):

The sql command text is executed when you instruct it with

```
 SQL.Execute
```

All you do before is change the command text three times before executing it.

You need to execute each one

```
 SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 1"
  SQL.Execute
 SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 2"
sql.Execute
SQL.CommandText = "UPDATE [dbMyDatabase].[dbo].[tbl_ExcelTest] SET [Value] =(?) WHERE [id] = 3"
sql.execute
```